# How do i deactivate a tinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce

On Chrome tinyMCE only deactivates the activated editor when a new one is activated, not when you click outside the editor. however i need it to, so i've built a small event for when i click the html-element.

I can get the activated editor without problem: `tinyMCE.activeEditor` but then i need it to deactivate.

Anyone got a clue?

Comment: what do you mean by "deactivating it"?

Comment: The editor have two events (onDeactivate & onActivate) its basicly focus and blur, aka when its selected. It can only be deselected by selecting another editor.

Comment: this is correct. Depending on what you want to achieve i could show you another way to reach your goal. Do you want to catch the activate event in order to do execute some code?